# El codigo que escribo en css no me está funcionando en mi intento de página

Tags: html, css, web

Cuando escribo el codigo,no me lo toma correctamente en el html de la página,
no se si la sintaxis o los atributos estan mal, quiero poner las 4 columnas correctamente en el footer de la pagina, pero no me edita el html con el css, dejo el código para que me puedan ayudar por favor ;c
pd: estoy casi recien aprendiendo a programar, no sean malos que no aprendo de malos comentarios.
[image: Lo que me aparece en la pagina]

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #DFDBE5;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='24' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M20 18c0-1.105.887-2 1.998-2 1.104 0 2-.895 2.002-1.994V14v6h-4v-2zM0 13.998C0 12.895.888 12 2 12c1.105 0 2 .888 2 2 0 1.105.888 2 2 2 1.105 0 2 .888 2 2v2H0v-6.002zm16 4.004A1.994 1.994 0 0 1 14 20c-1.105 0-2-.887-2-1.998v-4.004A1.994 1.994 0 0 0 10 12c-1.105 0-2-.888-2-2 0-1.105-.888-2-2-2-1.105 0-2-.887-2-1.998V1.998A1.994 1.994 0 0 0 2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2V0h8v2c0 1.105.888 2 2 2 1.105 0 2 .888 2 2 0 1.105.888 2 2 2 1.105 0 2-.888 2-2 0-1.105.888-2 2-2 1.105 0 2-.888 2-2V0h4v6.002A1.994 1.994 0 0 1 22 8c-1.105 0-2 .888-2 2 0 1.105-.888 2-2 2-1.105 0-2 .887-2 1.998v4.004z' fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.1' fill-rule='evenodd'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Navigation */
.nav-main {
    font-size: 17px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav-brand {
    width: 50px;
}
 /* NAV LEFT */
 .nav-main ul {
     display: flex;
 }
.nav-main ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}
.nav-main ul li a {
    padding: 2px;
}
.nav-main ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff ;
}
.nav-main ul.nav-menu {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

/* SHOWCASE */
hr {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.showcase {
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background: url(./img/patitas.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #262626;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.btn:hover {
    opacity: .9;
}
.showcase h2,
.showcase p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.showcase h3 {
    align-items: center;
}

/* ADDITIONAL INFORMATION */
.interes {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 10px 0;
    gap: 10px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.interes img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
}
.interes p {
    color: black;
}
.interes h3 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0;

}
.interes a {
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #0F7AF0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.interes a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* BANNER */
.info-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 358px;
    background: url(/img/banner.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.info-banner .content{
    width: 40%;
    padding: 90px 0 0 30px;
    color: white;
}

.info-banner p,
.info-banner h2 {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

/* SOCIAL
.social {
    margin: 20;
}

.social p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.social p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.links {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.links a {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.links a i {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
*/


/* FOOTER LINKS */
.footer-links {
    background: #2f3640;
    color: #616161;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 35px 0;
}

.footer-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer-container ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer-container ul li {
    line-height: 2.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nombre pagina</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- FONT OSWALD -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
     <!-- BARRA DE NAVEGACIÓN -->
        <nav class="nav-main">
        <img src="img/brand.jpg" alt="asa LOGO" class="nav-brand">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" >Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >Blochain</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >Artificil Intelligence</a>
            </li>           
            <li>
                <a href="#" >Machine learning</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >Quantum computing</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >Startup</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >More</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-menu-right">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
     <hr>
        <!-- SHOWCASE -->
        <header class="showcase">
            <h2>Nombre pagina</h2>
            <p><h3>¿Quienes somos?</h3><br>
                Somos una agrupación dedicada a ayudar a animales en situaciones complicadas, tambien nos dedicamos a difundir información sobre como cuidar a nuestros animalitos.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn" > Leer más<i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </header>

        <!-- Notas de Interés -->
        <div class="interes">
            <div>
                <img src="img/tenenciaresponsale.png" alt="Tenencia Responsable">
                <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni cumque recusandae laboriosam ut repellendus reiciendis labore deserunt illo blanditiis. Sunt.</p>
                <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angel-double-right"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/vacuna.jpg" alt="Vacunamiento">
                <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni cumque recusandae laboriosam ut repellendus reiciendis labore deserunt illo blanditiis. Sunt.</p>
                <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angel-double-right"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/cuidados.png" alt="Cuida a tu mascota">
                <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni cumque recusandae laboriosam ut repellendus reiciendis labore deserunt illo blanditiis. Sunt.</p>
                <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angel-double-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section class="info-banner">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores nulla necessitatibus fugit, eos neque quo quas voluptatem recusandae quos dicta?</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angle-"></a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Follow
        <section class="social">
            <p>Siguenos en nuestras redes</p>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </section> -->
    </div>

    <div class="footer-links">
        <div class="footer-container">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>Title One</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>Title One</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>Title One</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>Title One</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blockchain</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

No entiendo por que no me realiza los cambios en la pagina, por lo que he leido, deberia estar bien la sintaxis y los atributos

Comment: Puedes subir el código html y css como código y no como imagen? Así podemos hacer pruebas y ayudarte más facilmente. Gracias.

Comment: Ahí esta con el codigo amigo

Comment: Me sale perfecto, capaz es el navegador, podrías probar agregar en footer-links o footer-container un width:100%; desde css. Sino fijate que estén todos los divs bien cerrados, y que no esté dentro de algun padre que pueda estar limitando su ancho..

Comment: Carga la web desde una ventana de incógnito y asegúrate de resetear la caché de tu navegador. Cuando se está haciendo pruebas con CSS es muy importante solicitar la web sin caché siempre, puesto que los navegadores pueden ofrecer la web cacheada para no tener que descargar contenido estático una y otra vez, puesto que el contenido estático suele ser igual siempre

Comment: Estoy trabajando con chrome, capaz pasá el código completo de ambos, así lo puedo probar tal cual..

Comment: Lo del caché no me funcionó, y probando en otros navegadores tampoco, usé opera.gx, google y firefox. dejaré el codigo completo de los 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes agregar al footer-links lo siguiente width:100vw
El "v" es de viewport, el "w" es de width.
Entonces tu clase .footer-links debe quedar así:

```
 .footer-links {
     background: #2f3640;
     color: #616161;
     font-size: 12px;
     padding: 35px 0;
     width: 100vw;
 }
```

Espero resuelva, estoy a las órdenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!! me funcionó de maravilla!

Comment: Me alegro mucho, por favor si podés aceptá la solución debes darle al check al costado de la respuesta y dale con la flechita arriba para votarla, ayuda a otros a saber que la respuesta funciona y a quien responde le sube la reputación.

Comment: Gracias gracias, lo de la flechita para arriba, me sale eso:¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente., asi que tranquilo, muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti, hasta la próxima!